# Import library zip in Python

Tags: python

I am looking at an older version of python code

```
from itertools import izip
```

but when I run it, it says

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'izip'
```

Anyone know how should I import?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3+ you just use `zip` instead. It's builtin, so you don't have to import it. Try using the [2to3 tool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html?highlight=2to3) to update the code automatically.